# Minecraft windows 10 help with random mob spawn command

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m making pretty much zombies on mince craft but I can’t figure out a good way to spawn them with out just using /summon at pre set points and having a long chain of command blocks set on either a timer or just connected by redstone. 
If there’s a way to have them spawn at random points within a ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ area or just a square radius I’d love it if you could help.

Comment: In MCJava you could use [`/spreadplayers`](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/spreadplayers), I'm not sure about MCBE.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`/spreadplayers`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/spreadplayers):

```
/spreadplayers x z spreadDistance maxRange target
```

where

- `x` and `z`: the x- and z-coordinates of the centre
- `spreadDistance`: the minimum distance between the entities
- `maxRange` the maximum horizontal distance to spread the entities from the centre specified in `x` and `z` (must be at least `spreadDistance` + 1)
- `taget`: the entities to spread

For example, to “summon” zombies at least 1 block apart in a 7 × 7 square centred at your current position, you need to first summon the zombies:

```
summon zombie
```

and then teleport them using `spreadplayers`:

```
spreadplayers ~ ~ 1 3 @e[type=zombie,x=~,y=~,z=~,dx=1,dy=1,dz=1]
```